# Error in UseMethod("html_table") : no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a table from Basketballreference.com however I keep getting the same error and do not know how to resolve it. I am using this code:

```
'url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2019.html"

draft2019 <- url %>%
 read_html() %>%
 html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="stats"]')
%>%
 html_table()
 draft2019 <- draft2019[[1]]

head(draft2019)'
```

However I get the error at %>% and html_table(). The error is below:

```
'> %>%
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"
>   html_table()
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "NULL"'
```

Does anyone have a way to resolve this?

Comment: Your code is working on my side. `read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2019.html") %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="stats"]') %>% html_table()`. I wonder if the position of `%>%` (one before html_table()) is doing something.

Comment: have you found the solution for this error? i'm getting the same message...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just space alignment is needed in the syntax as pointed out by Jazzurro

```
url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/draft/NBA_2019.html"

draft2019 <- url %>%
 read_html() %>%
 html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="stats"]') %>%
 html_table()

draft2019 <- draft2019[[1]]

head(draft2019)
```